# How to send a variable to a NodeJS controller from an AngularJS service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have an AngularJS service called `sensorReadingsAPI`, which has the following function with `get`:

```
var _countSensorReadingsFilter = function () {
  return $http.get(config.baseUrl + "/sensorReading/countFilter").then(function (data,status) {
    sensorReadingCountFilter = data.data;
    return Number(sensorReadingCountFilter);
  }).catch(function() {});
};
```

The `/countFilter` is defined in a NodeJS controller:

```
module.exports = {
  countFilter: function (req, res) {
    return res.sensorReadingCountFilter();
  }
};
```

And `sensorReadingCountFilter` is as follows:

```
module.exports = function sensorReadingCountFilter(statusCode){

  var req = this.req;
  var res = this.res;

  SensorReading.count({deviceNum:'MBA002'}).exec(function countCB(error, found) {
    return res.view({val: found});
  });
};
```

Right now, the count is static (where is written `{deviceNum:'MBA002'}`). I need a way to make this value be dinamic, using a variable, preferably being send from the AngularJS controller. I have several devices, with the portential to add even more, and don't want to create a `/countFilter` module for each of them.

In other words, a way to send variables from an AngularJS service to a NodeJS controller. When searching for ways to do this, I have found next to nothing.

For clearance: all of this returns the number of readings from the selected device, and `config.baseUrl`is the local machine and port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use url parameters in your `$http.get('url-here?param1=1,param2=2')` and then you can access these params in your `req` object on the server side `req.query.param1`.

You also can specify params in config object of $http:

```
$http.get('my-url-here', { params: {deviceNum:'MBA002'} })
    .success()
    ...
```

Comment: I wouldn't say "also". Using `params` is the right way to do it. Composing an URL manually usually ends up with missing `encodeURIComponent` calls.

Comment: I was unaware that it was possible to use url parameters using `?param`. This is exactly what I need.

Comment: As a side note, do you know if it's best practice to let the server side (in this case, NodeJS) handle DB requests, or can I do them directly from AngularJS?

Comment: Server side. Between your angular app and api you are using RESTful API (I assume) and probably some security layer where DB connections usually using different protocols. I don't even know if you can do DB connection management form Angular with exception probably on couple No-Sql DB's.